# Terminal throws error message of some installation

Tags: command-line

Whenever i open terminal, it opens with the following undesired message:

```
32bit Detected
Installing Google Chrome
--2017-03-11 22:27:37--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-    stable_current_i386.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 216.58.220.174,2404:6800:4009:801::200e
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|216.58.220.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-03-11 22:27:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.
krishna@krishna-Inspiron-1545:~$
```

Could anyone please explain how to get rid of this message?

Below are my ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc files:

profile:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
# The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
# PS1='\h:\w\$ '
if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
  . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi
else
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PS1='# '
else
  PS1='$ '
fi
fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
if [ -r $i ]; then
  . $i
fi
done
unset i
fi
```

bashrc :

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi

# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin"        ] ; then
case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *)
if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
cat <<-EOF
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

EOF
fi
esac
fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found      /command-not-found ]; then
function command_not_found_handle {
        # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
            if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
       /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
               return $?
            elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ];     then
       /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
               return $?
    else
       printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
       return 127
    fi
}
fi
```

Comment: Can you upload your `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`? I suspect something has been added there (possibly by an installer)

Comment: @AaronHill I've edited my post to include ~/.profile and ~.bashrc files, could you please have a look at them and let me know how to get rid of the error message?